# Nested Models in Form are not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

For some reason I can't figure out why the nested elements are not appearing in this edit form.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pages
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
end
```

Heres the form

```
<%= form_for(:book) do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.text_field(:title) %></p>
  <%= f.fields_for :pages do |page| %>
    <p><%= page.text_field(:page_no) %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
def edit
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
end
```

It displays the title of the book but nothing appears when it goes to list the `page_no`s. Also I tried calling `:pages` and it returns an array of pages so I don't see why the form isn't being built.

Am I overlooking something in the model I need to change?

Comment: Can you add your controller code?

Comment: add the controller code and change `belongs_to :book` instead `belongs_to :Book`

Comment: I added the controller for that view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
```

instead of

```
<%= form_for(:book) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Do you have `resources :books` in your routes? (That's another problem)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add

```
attr_accessible :pages_attributes
```

to the Book model

Answer (score -1):

Try using build.

```
def edit
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  @book.pages.build
end
```